# Как сделать скриншота экрана и окна с помощью DirectX C#?

Tags: c#, directx, screenshots

Нужно сделать скриншот экрана и окна на C# и сохранить в любом виде в коде(Не в файл). Пробывал сделать через GDI.

```
 public static Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        IntPtr windowPtr = hwnd;
        Rect windowRect = new Rect();
        WindowsManager.GetWindowRect(windowPtr, ref windowRect);
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(windowRect.Left, windowRect.Top, windowRect.Right - windowRect.Left, windowRect.Bottom - windowRect.Top);
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
        {
            WindowsManager.PrintWindow(windowPtr, g.GetHdc(), 0);
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Но данным способом нельзя сделать скриншот окна которое рисуется не виндой. К тому же способ очень медленный как я знаю. Поэтому решил сделать через DirectX но в нём ничего не шарю, а информации не столь много по этой теме.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Создаю .NET 6 консольное приложение
- Ставлю NuGet пакеты: **System.Drawing.Common**, **SharpDX**, **SharpDX.DXGI**, **SharpDX.Direct3D11**

Пишу вот такой код

```
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace DXScreenshot;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = "screenshot.png";
        using var bmp = TakeScreenshot();
        bmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = path, UseShellExecute = true });
    }

    static Bitmap TakeScreenshot()
    {
        var factory = new Factory1();
        var adapter = factory.GetAdapter1(0);
        Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description1.Description);
        var device = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(adapter);
        Output output = adapter.GetOutput(0);
        Console.WriteLine(output.Description.DeviceName);
        Output1 output1 = output.QueryInterface<Output1>();

        int width = output.Description.DesktopBounds.Right;
        int height = output.Description.DesktopBounds.Bottom;

        Texture2DDescription textureDesc = new Texture2DDescription
        {
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read,
            BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
            Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            MipLevels = 1,
            ArraySize = 1,
            SampleDescription = { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging
        };
        using Texture2D screenTexture = new Texture2D(device, textureDesc);
        using OutputDuplication duplicatedOutput = output1.DuplicateOutput(device);
        Thread.Sleep(20); // захватчику экрана надо время проинициализироваться
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        SharpDX.DXGI.Resource screenResource = null;
        try
        {
            if (duplicatedOutput.TryAcquireNextFrame(10, out OutputDuplicateFrameInformation duplicateFrameInformation, out screenResource) != Result.Ok)
                return bmp;

            using (Texture2D screenTexture2D = screenResource.QueryInterface<Texture2D>())
            {
                device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(screenTexture2D, screenTexture);
            }

            DataBox mapSource = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(screenTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags.None);
            BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
            nint sourcePtr = mapSource.DataPointer;
            nint destPtr = bmpData.Scan0;
            Utilities.CopyMemory(destPtr, sourcePtr, mapSource.RowPitch * height);
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(screenTexture, 0);
            duplicatedOutput.ReleaseFrame();
        }
        catch (SharpDXException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            screenResource?.Dispose();
        }
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

Запускаю, и картинка на экране.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Несмотря на `Thread.Sleep` это очень быстрый способ делать скрины. На самом деле `OutputDuplication` можно проинициализировать однократно, а скриншотов можно делать потом с него сколько угодно и очень быстро, хоть видео с экрана писать можно.

Comment: Спасибо, можно ли через `OutputDuplication` сделать скриншот окна? И раз уж вы сказали что можно видео записывать, задам ещё один вопрос. Есть способ лучше чем создания милионов скриншотов?

Comment: @Deril скин окна можно сделать, для этого нужно знать его координаты и размер, а затем просто кропнуть битмап по получившемуся прямоугольнику. По поводу видео не подскажу, не занимался.

Comment: а если речь идёт о свёрнутом окне? Что-то на подобии PrintWindow есть в DirectX?

Comment: @Deril возможно, я не уверен что окно вообще себя рисует в свернутом виде. В любом случае, я не спец по DX, пример создал на основе других примеров.

Comment: OBS ведь захватывает закрытое окно и Discord так умеет скорее вмего способ есть