# Производительность сборки Release и запуск из VS22

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, dll, обработка-изображений

У меня очень странная проблема.
Я использую WPF-приложение для получения кадров изображения с устройства.
Связь с устройством осуществляется путем вызова методов из c++ dll

вот так

```
   [DllImport(DLL_FILE_PATH, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)].
public static extern uint Acquisition_Init();
```

Когда я запускаю сборку из Visual Studio 2022 (Release или Debug) - приложение запускается  все ок и **кадры идут со скоростью 45 FPS**.

Но когда я запускаю только что собранный .exe файл из папки Release - **FPS достигает максимум 30 FPS.**
В чем может быть причина такого странного поведения?
В чем отличие запуска приложения из Visual Studio и просто .exe из Release ?

С каких пор программа, запущенная через Visual Studio, работает быстрее и лучше, чем простая Release версия?

Comment: Начните с определения, места которое начинает "тормозить".

Comment: @Vasek кадры идут в одном случае со скорость 45 FPS, а в другом 30

Comment: Разрядность какая сборки? Не Any CPU случаем?

Comment: И 45 fps - это либо очень медленный комп, либо очень медленный код. Либо вы неправильно fps вычисляете. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1429147/373567

Comment: Нашел решение - дело было в системном таймере https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612236/why-is-my-c-sharp-program-faster-in-a-profiler/38404066#38404066