# Как сделать скриншот всего экрана из консольного приложения .NET 6 с помощью GDI+?

Tags: c#, gdi+, .net-6

Мне нужно делать скриншот экрана в некоторый момент выполнения программы, я находил несколько ответов как это делать, но они не работают. Я включал System.Windows.Forms и System.Drawing в проект, скачивал через nuget System.Drawing.Common который решает ошибки при компиляции, но при попытке сделать скриншот выдает ошибку о GDI+, пытался добавить ссылки на эти же библиотеки в COM, но всё тщетно.

Текущий код:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bitmap.Size);

bitmap.Save("C:\\img.png");
```

Comment: Точный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос. Какая версия .NET?

Comment: Текст ошибки - A generic error occurred in GDI+, версия .net core 6.0

Comment: Через Winforms если делаете, то скорее всего функция не может определить текущий монитор, так как консольное приложение не имеет такого же окна как Winforms приложение. Сейчас поищу решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Forms не нужно, это лишнее.

1. Создаю пустое .NET 6 приложение.

2. Устанавливаю NuGet пакет [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/)

3. Правлю `TargetFramework` проекта на `net6.0-windows`, чтобы IDE не ругалась о несовместимости приложения с другими платформами.

В результате .csproj файл выглядит вот так

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

4. Разрешение моего монитора 3840x2400, то есть потребуется поддержка мониторов с высоким DPI. Чтобы она появилась, просто вызову метод WinAPI `SetProcessDPIAware`, и тогда система будет знать, что мое приложение умеет работать с физическими мониторами с DPI, отличным от 96.

Получается такой код:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ScreenshotGdi;

class Program 
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();

    static Size GetMonitorSize()
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
        using Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(hwnd);
        return new Size((int)g.VisibleClipBounds.Width, (int)g.VisibleClipBounds.Height);
    }

    static Bitmap TakeScreenshot(Size size)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
        using Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
        return bmp;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetProcessDPIAware();
        Size monitorSize = GetMonitorSize();
        using Bitmap bitmap = TakeScreenshot(monitorSize);
        bitmap.Save("img.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

И вот такой скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делать скриншоты можно еще с помощью DirectX

- [Как сделать скриншота экрана и окна с помощью DirectX C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1429141/373567)

Comment: Спасибо большое за проделанную работу!

Comment: @Dreger не за что, обратите внимание, что `SetProcessDPIAware` нужно вызвать один раз на всё время работы приложения. Если делаете несколько скриншотов, то не нужно вызывать перед каждым.